# Cannot get code worked as in source code Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I know there are many ways to get to Rome, but I like to know what I did wrong with the copied code from a book I used. I think I know the answer, but do not know how to correct it.

The GUI:

[image: GUI]

When I copied the code from the book, it does not run, the result I get looks like this:

[image: Result]

The code that worked for me is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RadioButtonsTestForm
{
    public partial class RadioButtonsTestForm : Form
    {
        private MessageBoxIcon iconType;
        private MessageBoxButtons buttonType;

        public RadioButtonsTestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This is your Custom MessageBox.", "Custom MessageBox", buttonType, iconType);

            switch (result)
            {
                case DialogResult.OK:
                    displayLabel.Text = "OK was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    displayLabel.Text = "Cancel was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Abort:
                    displayLabel.Text = "Abort was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Retry:
                    displayLabel.Text = "Retry was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Ignore:
                    displayLabel.Text = "Ignore was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    displayLabel.Text = "Yes was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    displayLabel.Text = "No was pressed.";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void okRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType=MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        }

        private void okCancelRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
        }

        private void abortRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;
        }

        private void yesNoCancelRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
        }

        private void yesNoRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        }

        private void retryRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;
        }

        private void asteriskRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk;
        }

        private void errorRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
        }

        private void exclamationRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;
        }

        private void handRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Hand;
        }

        private void informationRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
        }

        private void questionRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
        }

        private void stopRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Stop;
        }

        private void warningRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Warning;
        }        
    }
}
```

The code used in the book is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RadioButtonsTest_3
{
    public partial class RadioButtonTestForm : Form
    {
        private MessageBoxButtons ButtonType;
        private MessageBoxIcon IconType;

        public RadioButtonTestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonType_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == OKRadioButton)
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            else if (sender == OKCancelRadioButton)
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
            else if (sender == AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton)
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;
            else if (sender == YesNoCancelRadioButton)
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
            else if (sender == YesNoRadioButton)
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
            else 
                ButtonType = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;
        }

        private void IconType_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == AsteriskRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk;
            else if (sender == ErrorRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            else if (sender == ExclamationRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;
            else if (sender == HandRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Hand;
            else if (sender == InformationRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
            else if (sender == QuestionRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
            else if (sender == StopRadioButton)
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Stop;
            else 
                IconType = MessageBoxIcon.Warning;
        }

        private void DisplayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This is your Custom MessageBox.", "Custom MessageBox", ButtonType, IconType);

            switch (result)
            {
                case DialogResult.OK:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "OK was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "Cancel was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Abort:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "Abort was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Retry:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "Retry was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Ignore:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "Ignore was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "Yes was pressed.";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    OutputLabel.Text = "No was pressed.";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure about it myself, but I think the mistake is how to get the ButtonType/IconType_CheckedChanged (just typed it in the code). Double-click on the DisplayButton get me DisplayButton_Clicked, but I don't know how to do that with the Button/IconType.

EDIT:

Designercode:

```
namespace RadioButtonsTest_3
{
    partial class RadioButtonTestForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ButtonGroupBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.IconGroupBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.DisplayButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.OutputLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.OKRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.OKCancelRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.YesNoRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.AsteriskRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.ErrorRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.ExclamationRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.HandRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.InformationRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.QuestionRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.StopRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.WarningRadioButton = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.ButtonGroupBox.SuspendLayout();
            this.IconGroupBox.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // ButtonGroupBox
            // 
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.RetryCancelRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.YesNoRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.YesNoCancelRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.OKCancelRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.OKRadioButton);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 13);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Name = "ButtonGroupBox";
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 172);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.TabIndex = 0;
            this.ButtonGroupBox.TabStop = false;
            this.ButtonGroupBox.Text = "ButtonType";
            // 
            // IconGroupBox
            // 
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.WarningRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.StopRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.QuestionRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.InformationRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.HandRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.ExclamationRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.ErrorRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.AsteriskRadioButton);
            this.IconGroupBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(171, 13);
            this.IconGroupBox.Name = "IconGroupBox";
            this.IconGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 211);
            this.IconGroupBox.TabIndex = 1;
            this.IconGroupBox.TabStop = false;
            this.IconGroupBox.Text = "Icon";
            // 
            // DisplayButton
            // 
            this.DisplayButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 191);
            this.DisplayButton.Name = "DisplayButton";
            this.DisplayButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(143, 33);
            this.DisplayButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.DisplayButton.Text = "Display";
            this.DisplayButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.DisplayButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DisplayButton_Click);
            // 
            // OutputLabel
            // 
            this.OutputLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.OutputLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 227);
            this.OutputLabel.Name = "OutputLabel";
            this.OutputLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(286, 23);
            this.OutputLabel.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // OKRadioButton
            // 
            this.OKRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.OKRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 20);
            this.OKRadioButton.Name = "OKRadioButton";
            this.OKRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 17);
            this.OKRadioButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.OKRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.OKRadioButton.Text = "OK";
            this.OKRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // OKCancelRadioButton
            // 
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 44);
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.Name = "OKCancelRadioButton";
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(73, 17);
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.Text = "OKCancel";
            this.OKCancelRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton
            // 
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 68);
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.Name = "AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton";
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 17);
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.Text = "AbortRetryIgnore";
            this.AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // YesNoCancelRadioButton
            // 
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 92);
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.Name = "YesNoCancelRadioButton";
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 17);
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.TabIndex = 3;
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.Text = "YesNoCancel";
            this.YesNoCancelRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // YesNoRadioButton
            // 
            this.YesNoRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.YesNoRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 116);
            this.YesNoRadioButton.Name = "YesNoRadioButton";
            this.YesNoRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 17);
            this.YesNoRadioButton.TabIndex = 4;
            this.YesNoRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.YesNoRadioButton.Text = "YesNo";
            this.YesNoRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // RetryCancelRadioButton
            // 
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 140);
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.Name = "RetryCancelRadioButton";
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(83, 17);
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.TabIndex = 5;
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.Text = "RetryCancel";
            this.RetryCancelRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // AsteriskRadioButton
            // 
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 20);
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.Name = "AsteriskRadioButton";
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 17);
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.Text = "Asterisk";
            this.AsteriskRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // ErrorRadioButton
            // 
            this.ErrorRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.ErrorRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 44);
            this.ErrorRadioButton.Name = "ErrorRadioButton";
            this.ErrorRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 17);
            this.ErrorRadioButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.ErrorRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.ErrorRadioButton.Text = "Error";
            this.ErrorRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // ExclamationRadioButton
            // 
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 68);
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.Name = "ExclamationRadioButton";
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 17);
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.Text = "Exclamation";
            this.ExclamationRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // HandRadioButton
            // 
            this.HandRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.HandRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 92);
            this.HandRadioButton.Name = "HandRadioButton";
            this.HandRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 17);
            this.HandRadioButton.TabIndex = 3;
            this.HandRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.HandRadioButton.Text = "Hand";
            this.HandRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // InformationRadioButton
            // 
            this.InformationRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.InformationRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 116);
            this.InformationRadioButton.Name = "InformationRadioButton";
            this.InformationRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 17);
            this.InformationRadioButton.TabIndex = 4;
            this.InformationRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.InformationRadioButton.Text = "Information";
            this.InformationRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // QuestionRadioButton
            // 
            this.QuestionRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.QuestionRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 140);
            this.QuestionRadioButton.Name = "QuestionRadioButton";
            this.QuestionRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(67, 17);
            this.QuestionRadioButton.TabIndex = 5;
            this.QuestionRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.QuestionRadioButton.Text = "Question";
            this.QuestionRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // StopRadioButton
            // 
            this.StopRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.StopRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 164);
            this.StopRadioButton.Name = "StopRadioButton";
            this.StopRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 17);
            this.StopRadioButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.StopRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.StopRadioButton.Text = "Stop";
            this.StopRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // WarningRadioButton
            // 
            this.WarningRadioButton.AutoSize = true;
            this.WarningRadioButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 188);
            this.WarningRadioButton.Name = "WarningRadioButton";
            this.WarningRadioButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 17);
            this.WarningRadioButton.TabIndex = 7;
            this.WarningRadioButton.TabStop = true;
            this.WarningRadioButton.Text = "Warning";
            this.WarningRadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // RadioButtonTestForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 394);
            this.Controls.Add(this.OutputLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.DisplayButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.IconGroupBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ButtonGroupBox);
            this.Name = "RadioButtonTestForm";
            this.Text = "RadioButtons";
            this.ButtonGroupBox.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ButtonGroupBox.PerformLayout();
            this.IconGroupBox.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.IconGroupBox.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox ButtonGroupBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton RetryCancelRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton YesNoRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton YesNoCancelRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton AbortRetryIgnoreRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton OKCancelRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton OKRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox IconGroupBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton WarningRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton StopRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton QuestionRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton InformationRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton HandRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton ExclamationRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton ErrorRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton AsteriskRadioButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button DisplayButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label OutputLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: So it looks like you have a changed event for each radio button whereas they use a single handler for all the radio buttons in the group. Both type look valid as long as you have the designer code correct. Did you form actually have all the controls pointing at the correct handler? We have no idea because we can't see your designer code. If you want us to be able to help you have to either a) include all relevant code (in this case the designer) or b) describe the actual error. Saying "this code didn't work" doesn't help at all. Preferably of course do both of these things...

Comment: For the code from the book, you haven't hooked up your CheckedChanged event for the radio buttons in `Button Type` group and `Icon` group to the EventHandler `IconType_CheckedChanged` and `ButtonType_CheckedChanged` respectively. For your own code, you hooked them up to event handler, albeit a separate one for each radio button (which does not play a role in correctness).

Comment: Hi, this is the designer code:

Comment: Thank you Chris and Vikhram, the book I have been using never mentioned about hooking up those controls to the handler. At least not as in the source code, it does as separate ones that I have been coding.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the designer and select one of the radio buttons and hit F4 (to bring up the properties window)

[image]

Click the lighting bolt at the top to go to the events. Go down and find check changed and from the dropdown select your event you have already coded.

Do this for *all* the radio buttons selecting ButtonType or Icon type based on whatever column they are in.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I don't have CheckChanged in my properties, just Checked.

Comment: @Edward79 make sure the radio button is selected in the designer. Click on it first. It should say radioButton something at the top (or whatever you named it) where it says radioButton1 in the screenshot

Comment: SOLVED it. Just as Brandon told. Anyway, thank you all for your time and comments.